# my php file called by post method in javascript cant access sessions why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

Hello everybody I am trying to write simple comments for my website. I somehow found how to use jquery for it but when I call post method from that query I cant access `$_SESSION('jmeno')` and I rly dont know what I missing.. 
There is my code

html ..

```
<li><input name="com" class="komentar" type="text" placeholder="Váš komentář..." IDCard="<?php echo $IDcard ?>" /></li>
```

js :

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="/../jquery.js"></SCRIPT>
            <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" >

                $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('.komentar').keyup(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){

            var IDcard = $(this).attr('IDcard');
            var comment = $(this).val();
            $.post('commentService.php',{ IDcard: IDcard, comment: comment});
            $(this).val('');
        }
        });
    });
            </SCRIPT>
```

and my commentService.php looks like this:

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 

define('DBHOST', 'localhost');           
define('DBNAME', 'n2mu');               
define('DBUSER', '****');               
define('DBPASS', '****');                   

@mysql_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS) or die (mysql_error()); 
@mysql_select_db(DBNAME) or die (mysql_error()); 

@session_start();

    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $IDcard = $_POST['IDcard'];
    $jmeno = $_SESSION['jmeno'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `card_com` VALUES('".  mysql_real_escape_string($IDcard)."', '".  mysql_real_escape_string($jmeno)."', '".  mysql_real_escape_string($comment)."', now() );");
    ?>
```

If you could help me that would be awesome!

Comment: You need to use `session_start();`. Put it as first line for commentService.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see where you defined the variable. In general, here's how they work;

```
 /* page1.php */
 <?php
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['jmeno'] = "foo";


 ?>

 /* page2.php */
 <?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['jmeno']; //prints out foo

 ?>
```

Make sure you run page1.php first before running page2.php so that the session variable can be defined or initialized. It's crucial to make sure that you include the

```
 session_start();
```

function at the very top of every page. So whether you access the pages directly through the browser or through javascript, it doesn't matter the contents of the variable will always be the same.

Comment: I just found what went wrong ^^  Thats exactly what I did not. thank you

Comment: I thought there is some huge problem. But the real problem was in my head. Sorry guys...

Comment: that happens a lot to everyone. It's called debugging. You're welcome